# how to set value to some desired index of array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have saving cart items in localStorage of javascript.
I use **product_id** for **index** of array in javascript, this array contain of object with some property.

```
let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
cart[cartObject.product_id] = {
    quantity : cartObject.product_quantity,
    price : cartObject.product_price,
    holding : cartObject.product_holding
}
localStorage.setItem('cart' , JSON.stringify(cart));
```

the problem is for example when my product_id is 8, localStorage is :

0: null

1: null

2: null

4: null

5: null

6: null

7: null

8: {quantity: 15, price: 16000, holding: 44}

what about 4000 ? is localStorage goes overflow ?

this problem does not exist in php, I want to access directly to specific index of array.
for example get `cart[4432].price`.

how to do that ?

thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? Nothing prevents you to do `card[4432]` in JavaScript. Array can accept any index, but for performance reasons is advised to use objects if the indices are sparse

Comment: how to use object with key index like array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the way you store the products. Instead of using an Array, you can use an Object.

```js
// Suppose localStorage.getItem('cart') contains an {} instead of []

let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')); // Should return {}

cart[cartObject.product_id] = {
    quantity : cartObject.product_quantity,
    price : cartObject.product_price,
    holding : cartObject.product_holding
}

localStorage.setItem('cart' , JSON.stringify(cart)); // Should save {"product_id": {"quantity": 1, "price": 100, "holding": "product_holder"}}

// If you want to loop like an Array, you would do the following:
Object.values(cart).forEach(function(product) {
  // Do something with your product...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that you use arrays for your task. A better way would be to use maps:

```
let cart = new Map( JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('cart') ) );

cart.set( cartObject.product_id, {
  quantity : cartObject.product_quantity,
  price : cartObject.product_price,
  holding : cartObject.product_holding,
});

localStorage.setItem( 'cart', Array.from( cart ) );
```

Comment: Now can I access to `cart[4432].quantity` ?

Comment: @arefrazavi You can access it via `cart.get( 4432 ).quantity` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get for reference)

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your code like this:

```
var colors=["red","blue"];
var index=1;

//insert "white" at index 1
colors.splice(index, 0, "white");   //colors =  ["red", "white", "blue"]
```