# how to set sparse index in array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to set for example :

```
myarray[3922] = {
    name : 'john'
    family : 'doe'
}
```

which did not make null indices like this :

myarray[0] = null

myarray[1] = null

.

.

.

myarray[3920] = null

myarray[3921] = null

myarray[3922 = {
name : 'john'
family : 'doe'
}

so that I can have direct access to `myarray[3922].name` .

I use these for saving in localStorage, like this:
[how to set value to some desired index of array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73591463/how-to-set-value-to-some-desired-index-of-array-in-javascript/73591509?noredirect=1#comment129960712_73591509)

thanks in advance

Comment: Just don't use an array. Use an object instead.

Comment: I don't found any source of how to make that object for direct access

Comment: What's wrong with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73591585/9473764) to your previous question?